# css prettifier AND condenser

Tags: css

Hey I have a problem which is two part but the first one is obviously where I must begin:

I have inherited a project which has three stylesheets, desktop.css, tablet.css, and mobile.css - they are called like so on the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/tablet.css" media="all and (min-width:600px) and (max-width:799px)" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile.css" media="all and (min-width:10px) and (max-width:599px)" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/desktop.css" media="all and (min-width:800px) " />
```

However the programmers before me were in a hurry and really, most of the code is the same; they just made tweaks per file as needed.  Probably 90% of the code is the same.

My goal is to have a common stylesheet first as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/UNIVERSAL.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/tablet.css" media="all and (min-width:600px) and (max-width:799px)" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile.css" media="all and (min-width:10px) and (max-width:599px)" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/desktop.css" media="all and (min-width:800px) " />
```

and get all common css into universal.css, and include on the other files only the "overrides" needed for that particular device.

All three files are a mess.  There are multiple instances of a class/id declarations.  They are quite out of order. I know there are CSS prettifiers out there, but is there any application which will take a CSS file, "READ" it, and re-output it in a condensed format?

It would be also nice to do a diff on the css and see what's different.  DIFF itself is not going to work because of being out of order in probably multiple ways.  So if you know anything in this regard, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Look at the advanced options: http://devilo.us/#

Comment: went there.  I do see the grouping and merging but they're down, I get a parse error PHP when submitting:

Fatal error: Call to a member function addBlock() on a non-object in /kunden/pyramedia.de/_pyramedia/leo/devilo.us/lib/Parser.php on line 517

Answer (score 1):

Check the advanced options of [proCSSor](http://tools.maxcdn.com/procssor/)